# Jenkins cannot find Jenkinsfile in Multibranch Project

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, rtc

I am configuring a multi-branch Jenkins pipeline using a `Jenkinsfile` at the root of the Project directory. Using the latest version of Jenkins 2.89.4. The build log follows:

```
Started by user USERNAME

Checking out teamconcert-URL Build Toolkit 4.0.4-bd-app-jboss-ci-dev into C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\APP_JBoss\branches\aapp-jboss-ci-dev.su0lgd\workspace@script to read Jenkinsfile

RTC : checkout...

RTC Checkout : Source control setup

RTC Checkout : Accepting changes into workspace "Jenkins JBOSS CI" ...

Using build definition configuration.

Fetching files from repository workspace "Jenkins JBOSS CI".

RTC Checkout : Deleting fetch destination "E:\JENKINS_DATA\app-jboss-dev" before fetching ...

RTC Checkout : Fetching files to fetch destination "E:\JENKINS_DATA\app-jboss-dev" ...

RTC Checkout : Fetching Completed

ERROR: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\APP_JBoss\branches\app-jboss-ci-dev.su0lgd\workspace@script\Jenkinsfile not found

Finished: FAILURE
```

I do not understand what that last ERROR line means. Jenkins seems to be cloning the Jenkinsfile from source control, copying it into
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\APP_JBoss\branches\aapp-jboss-ci-dev.su0lgd\workspace` and then attempt to read it back after cloning the entire repository into the build workspace at `E:\JENKINS_DATA\app-jboss-dev`.

Why can it not find the Jenkinsfile? I placed the Jenkinsfile at both the root and inside a `script` folder as well (just in case).

- I am pulling from an RTC build definition.
- I created a simple pipeline job as well (forget about the multi-branch setup). Jenkins is still unable to find the Jenkinsfile. (same issue).
- I confirmed the repository is cloned correctly from RTC (version control system) as I can see the file in the directory and it is intact.
- I edited the workspace directory and created this directory. Jenkins still wasnt able to find the file.
- Jenkins is not copying anything into the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\APP_JBoss\branches\app-jboss-ci-dev.su0lgd\workspace` file. No error message indicates that this step failed.
  Can you please explain the dynamics of this process, I am out of ideas as to how to resolve this issue.